# Double underscore to assignment - Sublime and R

Tags: r, sublimetext2, sublimetext

In Vim, when editing R scripts, I have mapped double underscore `__` to the assignment operator `<-`. How can I do the same in Sublime Text 2?

Comment: For vast majority of cases, '=' works perfectly well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use Snippets. In Sublime click on Tools > New Snippet.

```
<snippet>
<content><![CDATA[
<-
]]></content>
<!-- Optional: Set a tabTrigger to define how to trigger the snippet -->
<tabTrigger>__</tabTrigger>
<!-- Optional: Set a scope to limit where the snippet will trigger -->
<scope>source.r</scope>
</snippet>
```

Save this as something like PHP.sublime-snippet. Now, whenever you type "__" and tab it will be changed to <-.

Comment: Thank you. How can I make the snippet extension-specific? That is, I only want to use this shortcut for `.R` files.

Comment: When you press Cmd+Shift+P on Mac you get to choose the Syntax. The part of my code where it says <scope>source.r</scope> already means it will only trigger when you use R-Syntax. When you save a file to R it should automatically use R-Syntax highlighting as well, without you selecting it.

Answer (score 0):

Under `Preferences > Key Bindings` add

```
   { "keys": ["_", "_"], 
     "command": "insert", 
     "args": {"characters": " <- "},
     "context": {"key": "selector", "operator": "equal", "operand": "source.r" }
   }
```

This automatically turns `__` to `<-` in `.R` files, without having to tab `Tab`.